# Replace (change) "Chapter 1" to "Chapter ONE"

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, formatting, chapters

I am writing a lab report, and select `report` class provided by LyX. I use LyX 2.0.3 and MiKTeX 2.9.

My question is, how to change the chapter number to display as text?

eg:

CHAPTER ONE not CHAPTER 1;

Also the same to be appear in the TOC

eg.:

```
CHAPTER ONE 
1.1...............
   1.1.1.........................
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's one possibility using the `\Numberstring` command from the `fmtcount` package to turn the number to its text string; the `tocloft` package was used to add the word "Chapter" before the chapter number in the ToC:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\Numberstring{chapter}}
\setlength\cftchapnumwidth{3em}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapter~}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{\bfseries\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum} % extra space
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylen}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter}

\end{document}
```

An image of the ToC:

[image]

An image of the first page of the chapter:

[image]

Comment: I got the following error, how I can fix it plz.\documentclass
                   {report} \usepackage{tocloft} \usepackage{fmtcount}
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

Comment: @MAHMDSHUGRAN are you getting this error with the exact code I posted in my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a direct patch of `\@chapter` - the macro responsible for setting the passing chapter content to the ToC, together with [`fmtcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount) for formatting the numbering of the chapter counter. The patch is thanks to [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\usepackage{fmtcount}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\NUMBERstring{chapter}}%
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}% <cmd>
  {\numberline{\thechapter}}% <search>
  {\@chapapp~\thechapter\quad}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{A section}\subsection{A subsection}\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\section{A section}\subsection{A subsection}\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\section{A section}\subsection{A subsection}\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{A section}\subsection{A subsection}\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\section{A section}\subsection{A subsection}\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\section{A section}\subsection{A subsection}\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\chapter{Third chapter}
\section{A section}\subsection{A subsection}\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\section{A section}\subsection{A subsection}\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\section{A section}\subsection{A subsection}\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\chapter{Last chapter}
\section{A section}\subsection{A subsection}\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\section{A section}\subsection{A subsection}\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\section{A section}\subsection{A subsection}\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\end{document}
```