# Replace (change) “Chapter 1” to “Chapter ONE” without affecting lof and lot

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I used the answer given here [Replace (change) "Chapter 1" to "Chapter ONE"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83172/replace-change-chapter-1-to-chapter-one) but it only should be in case without a following list of tables (lot) or figures (lof).
When used as it is, the following lot and lof also replace the chapter number with a word as shown:
[image]

[image]

What should be changed to prevent this?

Comment: Please also indicate how you would cross-references to chapters, figures, and tables to look like: Should they look like "Figure Two" or like "Figure 2"? Please also indicate which document class you use.

Comment: You tag this with [tag:titlesec]; if you're exploiting this package, we need to know how.

Comment: @Mico In cross-referencing the numbering should remain in arabic, (Figure 2.1 / Figure 3). Am using the report class.

Comment: @egreg Got the correction, am using the tocloft package not titlesec for toc, lof & lot.

Answer (score 4):

You don't mention in your question how you produced the string instead of the number. You mustn't redefine `\thechapter`, or all references pertaining to the first chapter will have the string `ONE`.

You can patch the `\@makechapterhead` instead, with the following:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fmtcount} % for textual representation of numbers

% patch \@makechapterhead
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
  {\thechapter}
  {\NUMBERstring{chapter}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\chapter{First}

\begin{figure}
A
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to have “CHAPTER ONE” in front of your chapter title in the table of contents, you need to patch also `\@chapter`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{CHAPTER\ }
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{10em}
\usepackage{fmtcount} % for textual representation of numbers

% patch \@makechapterhead and \@chapter
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
  {\thechapter}
  {\NUMBERstring{chapter}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}}
  {\protect\numberline{\protect\NUMBERstringnum{\arabic{chapter}}}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\chapter{First}

\begin{figure}
A
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you need `\cleardoublepage` before `\listoffigures`, if you want it in a new page. For showing the output I did not add it.

Comment: this code does not bring the expected output/effect. It affects the title in the body instead. I need to format the entry in the toc. It should read as 
Chapter One: .......1 not Chapter 1:.......1

Comment: @simo With the default setting, there is *no* “Chapter” in front of the chapter number in the TOC. Please specify better what you want in you question.

Comment: I've `\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{CHAPTER\; }` to take care of that. The issue is to have the chapter no. read as ONE not 1

Comment: @simo I added another patch for doing what you need.

Comment: @Bernard, @egreg;  I've tested this option but it can't work with `[titles]tocloft` package which am using to format the entries in the toc lof and lot

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using the [titletoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) and [fmtcount](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount) packages:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{titletoc,  fmtcount}

\newlength{\len}
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.2em]{\bfseries \bigskip}%
{\contentslabel[Chapter \Numberstringnum{\thecontentslabel}.]{0.6em}\settowidth{\len} {Chapter \Numberstringnum{\thecontentslabel}}\hspace*{\len}}%]
{\hspace*{-1.5em}}%
{\hfill\contentspage}%
[\smallskip]%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Down the Rabbit-Hole}

\section{Alice was beginning to get tired}

\section{Drink me.  Eat me. }

\setcounter{chapter}{10}
\chapter{Who Stole the Tarts?}

\section{The Queen’s Croquet-Ground}

\section{The Mock-Turtle’s Story}

\end{document}
```

It shouldn't modify any cross-references using the chapter counter. It is multilingual for a small number of language thanks to the `\FCloadlang` command.

[image: Here is the corresponding table of contents:]

Comment: this code does not bring the expected output/effect. It affects the title in the body instead. I need to format the entry in the toc. It should read as 
Chapter One: .......1 not Chapter 1:.......1

Comment: I had not well understood the requirements. I modified the solution accordingly.

Comment: @egreg;  I've tested this option but it can't work with `[titles]tocloft` package which am using to format the entries in the toc lof and lot

Comment: @simo: yes, as both titletoc's and tocloft's job is to format the table of contents, it's natural they can't be used together. I gave this solution to show it was easy to do with an alternative package.

Comment: Does it mean that I can't achieve the results with the `tocloft` package?

Comment: It only means that know how to do it with titletoc. As for toctloft, I don't know: I never used it, being perfectly happy with titletoc.

Comment: Am using `tocloft` coz of the requirements format of the `toc` `lot` & `lof` and also a newly created list of appendices. So, I can't do without it. `titletoc` will not provide for these requirements

Comment: Are you sure you can't satisfy the requirements with titletoc? It should at least be able to print a list of appendices with its \contentsuse command.